# Prolog: Get values from 0 to K - 1

Tags: prolog, range

I'm attempting to create a program where given N, I need Q = 0...N.

So if given N = 1: Q = 0. If given N = 5: Q = 0, Q = 1,...,Q = 4

My attempt so far:

```
values(N,Q) :- values_helper(0,N,Q).

values_helper(N, N, Q).
values_helper(X,N,Q) :- X0 is X + 1, X0 < N, values_helper(X0,N,X0).
```

My logic behind it is that I increment X until it reaches the value of N, at which point the program stops. However, I'm not getting any bindings for Q, just an empty set. I also know that I'm neglecting to stop at N - 1.

EDIT: Fixed up ambiguities with the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your values_helper clauses don't do what you expect. The first one succeeds if the first 2 arguments are the same, and doesn't impose any constraints on Q. What you actually want is that Q is set equal to the first argument, as long as it's smaller than the second argument:

```
values_helper(Q, N, Q) :- Q < N.
```

In the second clause, again you don't use Q anywhere. The recursive call should be `values_helper(X0, N, Q)`, giving:

```
values_helper(X, N, Q) :- X0 is X + 1, X0 < N, values_helper(X0, N, Q).
```

These clauses give the expected output:

```
?- values(5,Q).                                                           
Q = 0 ? ;
Q = 1 ? ;
Q = 2 ? ; 
Q = 3 ? ;
Q = 4 ? ;
no
```

Note that for any N <= 0, this terminates without finding any value for Q, which I believe is the expected behavior.